# A ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$ given as $ S(a,\rho) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid ||x-a|| < \rho \right\} $

Tags: real-analysis, spheres

Why is it  $ S(a,\rho) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid ||x-a|| < \rho \right\} $
and not $ S(a,\rho) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid ||x-a|| \le \rho \right\} $ ?

$a$ is centrum, $\rho$ is radius.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this terminologies. I know $\{x \in \Bbb{R}^k \mid \|x-a\| < \rho\}, \{x \in \Bbb{R}^k \mid \|x-a\| \leq \rho\}$ by ball (open and closed) and $\{x \in \Bbb{R}^k \mid \|x-a\| = \rho\}$ by sphere.

Comment: @Corrêa My mistake. I have corrected it. I still do not understand why it's not the second? Why is $\rho$ not included?

Comment: They are just names. But if you want to give names that make some sense, I think it reasonable to name the whole ball by ball and boundary of sphere. So, the sphere will be the ball (looking at the closed ball) minus its interior. Now about the $<,\leq$, it dependes on the type of ball, open or closed.

Comment: @ Thanks. Now I get it. $ S(a,\rho) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid ||x-a|| < \rho \right\} $ is a open ball.